# EF Databinding, editing, modifying, saving records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding, edit

I need a EF sample code to fill my Customer Form controls based on a value put in a search field. Take into account that the combos on this form are already filled, and the user can either create a new record or edit an existing one by specifying a value on a textBox. The combos are filled with database data (Names) from auxiliary tables like Country, State, City, etc. 
On the Customer table I have only Id's (Foreign Keys) for those names. So, on the form when the user puts the customer Id, if it doesn't exist we are creating a new record, else the form should load the entire record from the database and fill the correspondent fields on the form, including showing on the combos the names that match the Id's on the record, giving the user the option to modify any field and save it back.
 In a non-EF scenario I would have something like:

```
    private void txtId_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqlStrQuery = "Select FName, LName, Email, Phone, CountryId from Customer where ID= '" + txtId.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStrQuery, sqlConStr);

        sqlConStr.Open();
        SqlDataReader drCustomer = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (drCustomer.HasRows)
        {
            while (drCustomer.Read())
            {
                txtFirstName.Text = drCustomer.GetValue(1).ToString();
                txtlastName.Text = drCustomer.GetValue(2).ToString();
                txtEmail.Text = drCustomer.GetValue(3).ToString();
                txtPhone.Text = drCustomer.GetValue(4).ToString();
                cboCountry.SelectedValue = drCustomer.GetValue(5);

            }
        }

    }
```

How can I convert it into EF?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you wondering how to setup databinding for all of your text boxes? Such that, once you update drCustomer, all the textboxes get updated automatically, and when the user updates a textbox, the relevant field in your Customer object gets updated automatically too? Confirm this and I'll send you a code snippet and explain how it works.

Comment: Hi Opender! Not exactly, but it sounds quite interesting. Would you mind send me the snippet? Thanks in advance. BTW, I was using ADO.Net and now I'm converting all my code into Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a variable, say context, for your data context:

```
var customer = context.Customers.Find(txtId.Text);
if (customer != null)
{
    txtFirstName.Text = customer.FirstName;
    txtlastName.Text = customer.LastName;
    txtEmail.Text = customer.Email;
    txtPhone.Text = customer.Phone;
    cboCountry.SelectedValue = customer.CountryId;
}
```

Edit: To search for multiple criteria

```
var matches = context.Customers.AsQueryable();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLastName.Text))
{
     matches = matches.Where(m => m.LastName == txtLastName.Text);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text))
{
     matches = matches.Where(m => m.FirstName == txtFirstName.Text);
}
// repeat for searchable fields
return matches.ToList();
```

Comment: Hi partners! Sorry for the late reply, but internet around here is a commodity for the chosen few ;-D....
Steve, your suggestion "works", thanks. But only for scalar types like Int32, Guid, etc. The method assumes one is searching records using a primary key column. But I need to give the user the hability to search using other criteria like lastName, zip, etc., which represent normal fields on the table. I need something like:

var customer = context.Customers.FindIn(Column name, value to search for);
Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, I posted the LINQ equivalent of the example in the question. If you want something more dynamic, I edited the answer with one method.

Comment: Each time someone helps me out with a code snippet on EF, LINQ, etc, I get really excited about the capabilities of these technologies. I'm new at both....lots of kudos for you Steve and anyone who bothers to help.